# Who should take care of filling data class? Parser or Class?

Tags: java, xml, parsing, software-design

I'm having some doubts about software design when parsing an XML. Usually, I will create a class for every meaningful tag in the XML and then from the parser fill it with the attributes.

```
setElementListener(new ElementListener() {
    @Override
    public void start(Attributes attributes) {
        Object obj = new Object();
        obj.setAttribute(attributes.get("attName");
    }
}
```

Now, I have a big XML with many differentes objects, so my XMLParser class is becoming unstoppable from growing. We discussed that maybe in our object class create a static method that will handle the creation of the object from the attributes.

```
public static Object inflate(Attributes attributes) {
    Object result = new Object();

    obj.setAttribute(attributes.get("attName");

    return result;
}
```

Which of both ways is better?

**EDIT:**

The main problem with the second option is that I don't like the data class to know what Attributes is, it seems like not a good design.

Comment: I would suggest that let the parser only do the parsing, rest all can be done elsewhere.

Comment: what do you mean by "only do parsing"? Do you consider extracting the attributes of an XML tag as parsing? Also, do you consider as good design that the data class receive the Attributes object? Thanks.

Comment: a class that keeps growing is a good indication you went wrong somewhere. have you looked into JAXB? or Apache Digester?